# Trigger rails/active_record conditional validation without conditionals

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

I have a model that has three specific states: `draft`, `submitted` and `published`.

Each of these states has specific validation rules. E.g. the name of the model is only required in `submitted` and `published`. Something along the lines of:

```
validates :name, :presence => true, :unless => :draft?
```

When a `draft` model is on-screen, I want to show which broken validation rules have to be fixed, before being able to transition to `submitted`. When the model is in `draft`, the validation states that it is valid (which is true), but I still want to show the errors as if it were `submitted`.

I'm don't really know how I should tackle this problem.

Comment: Say your model is `Post`. Do you want to show the broken validations when the `draft` post will be saved as `published` or `submitted` state or just as long as the user will keep editing the post without title?

Answer (score 1):

I do something similar for one of my projects.  In my case, I have a virtual attribute that I can set to override the state.  Then in my version of the "draft?" method I check the virtual attribute, if the attribute "do_full_validation" is set to true, then I respond in a way that allows the validation to be executed.